# Modify category listing API response

Tags: filters, api

I have an existing site that uses a WordPress backend for publishing along with a custom Rails front end that displays the WP content (among other things).

One of the things I'm doing with the WordPress API is modifying the API responses for posts in order to add additional data and strip out the attributes I don't need on the front end. This is working great.

Now I'm trying to do something similar for categories. I'm building a page that will show WP categories and I'd like to modify the API response to include a category image URL (with category image functionality provided by the WPCustom Category Image plugin).

I found the existence of `rest_prepare_taxonomy` but it doesn't seem to behave the same way that `rest_prepare_post` does.

This is how I'm modifying my post queries (where `modify_api_post_response()` is the function I wrote to modify the response):

```
add_filter('rest_prepare_post', 'modify_api_post_response', 12, 3);
```

Doing the same with `rest_prepare_taxonomy` and another custom function has no effect on the response data.

```
add_filter('rest_prepare_taxonomy', 'modify_api_taxonomy_response');
```

I've tried a variety of priority values with the same result (ie, no change in what I get back from WP).

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the API to respond with one or more categories, you are querying for terms and not for taxonomies. So you should not be using `WP_REST_Taxonomies_Controller` but rather `WP_REST_Terms_Controller`.

Instead of hooking to the filter [`rest_prepare_taxonomy`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_prepare_taxonomy/), try hooking to [`rest_prepare_{$this->taxonomy}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_prepare_this-taxonomy/) instead. As you are working with the taxonomy "category" use it as `rest_prepare_category`:

```
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_category', 'modify_api_taxonomy_response', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Obvious in retrospect, but that had totally escaped me.